# Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content

Tags: c#, .net, json

So I was running the code below

```
JObject.Parse(input.ToString(Encoding.UTF8)).ToFlatDictionary())
```

And ran into this error message

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content

What does this mean? Other questions say I have to surround my JSON with []'s both ends but do I do this when sending it or? I'm a little confused. I basically send JSON between my client&server.

```
internal class JsonToPacketDecoder : ByteToMessageDecoder
{
    protected override void Decode(IChannelHandlerContext context, IByteBuffer input, List<object> output)
    {
        output.Add(new IncomingPacket(JObject.Parse(input.ToString(Encoding.UTF8)).ToFlatDictionary()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `input`?

Comment: The input is valid JSON. Here is the content: https://ghostbin.com/paste/v3xtd

Comment: That error just means json net read full object from your string, but then found something more after closing brace (something more can be another json object for example).